# Dynamically changing content of a cell dropdown for validation because of a huge list

Tags: worksheet-function, spreadsheet

I have a huge lookup list of items, each with a conversion factor that I wish to look up.

The lookup list is too big to be practical for a validation dropdown - this is how it looks:

[image]

Here's the lookup part, where the item must come from the lookup list to provide the conversion factor in the Factor column `{=IFNA(VLOOKUP(C5,SourceLookUp,3),0)}`:

[image]

What I would like to do is have an extra column between the date and the item column, where the user chooses the category first, and then that defines the validation dropdown content for the item column.

Is this possible?

Comment: `Is this possible?` yes.  But Google sheet question are off topic here and this question is too broad as you have not shown what research you have done and what you have tried.

Comment: Good point. But formulas are on topic.

Comment: How this is accomplished will be specific to the app you are using.  An answer in Excel could not work in Google sheets.  For example in Excel the only way to do this would be to have a dynamic array reload a list in a helper range and then refer to that helper range with the list.  You cannot use dynamic arrays in data validation.  The best way to handle this would be through vba in excel and that definitely will not translate to Google sheets

Comment: Also that still leaves the second part of the first comment in that you do not show what you have researched/tried. a Quick search brought: : https://www.contextures.com/exceldatavaldependdynamic.html https://trumpexcel.com/dependent-drop-down-list-in-excel/

Comment: I searched for hours. Actually, I didn't search for hours, I searched a little and then spent ages trying to understand whether the potential solutions I was looking at from all over the web would actually help. I didn't come across ```INDIRECT()``` but that is what I need. Thanks.